# How to use view as blocks in Scikit-Image?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I have a numpy array of shape `(12,224,224)`. This is 12 images of size `(244, 244)`. When I had a single image, this was simple. The image was of size `(x,y)`. For example, `x` is an image of size `(400,400)`, for which I could use `view_as_blocks` like this:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks as vablks
xx = vablks(x, block_shape=(8,8))
```

This would result in a block of shape `(50,50,8,8)`.
Now I would like to know how to apply this when I have a list of images. Either I lose shape, that is my 12 images are combined into one (224,224) block broken down into `(28,28,8,8)`, or I run into a ValueError. Here is the code I tried to use for iterating over the 12 images and viewing the `(224,224)` shaped images

```
xx = []
for item_ in x:
    xx.append(blockSplitter(item_))
```

where x is a list of images.

Here is the error:

```
ValueError: 'block_shape' is not compatible with 'arr_in'
```

Overall, I would like to know how to view the images as blocks of 8x8 without losing the images.
Help, Please and Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1) Convert the list to an array, as suggested by the commenter above.  Then use `view_as_blocks` with the correct parameters:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks
images = [np.zeros((50, 50)) for i in range(10)]
images = np.array(images)
all_blocks = view_as_blocks(images, block_shape=(1, 10, 10)).squeeze()
```

2) Convert each item in the list to a windowed view, and then convert the end result to an array:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks
images = [np.zeros((50, 50)) for i in range(10)]
image_blocks = [view_as_blocks(image, block_shape=(10, 10)) for image in images]
all_blocks = np.array(image_blocks)
```